# Input triggering action multiple times intermittently

Tags: unity-game-engine

Having trouble figuring out what's causing an intermittent bug. The issue is that sometimes the "explosionA" animation will trigger multiple times when either holding the A key or pressing it rapidly, but not always.

```
void Start() {
    aUsable = true;
    aCooldown = 0.5f;
    aTimer = 0;
}

void Update () {
    CooldownManager();
    Cast();
}

void Cast() {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && aUsable){
        spell.SetTrigger("explosionA");
        aUsable = false;
    }
}

void CooldownManager() {
    if (Time.time > aTimer){
        aUsable = true;
        aTimer = Time.time + aCooldown;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using `FixedUpdate` instead of `Update`?

Comment: That didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the  CooldownManager is called even if the aUsable bool is already true and could happen that the spell is triggered when the Time.time is very near to aTimer so the time that will pass before allow the next spell trigger is "aTimer - Time.time" that is less then aCooldown.

To fix it you can do:

```
void Cast() {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && aUsable){
        spell.SetTrigger("explosionA");
        aUsable = false;
        aTimer = Time.time + aCooldown;
    }
}

void CooldownManager() 
{
    if (!aUsable && Time.time >= aTimer)
    {
            aUsable = true;
            aTimer = Time.time + aCooldown;
    }
}
```

This should give you a right frequence on the spell trigger.

I hope this will fix your bug. 
Roberto

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the Cast() function

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && aUsable){
//...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'd like for the user to be able to hold down the key to continually use the ability as soon as it comes off cooldown.

Comment: I am not sure but maybe Spell.SetTrigger() function takes longer time to execute which causes the Cast() function to be executed again before the aUsable flag is set to false ? I see a quite similar implementation of firing rate at Unity Docs here: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html .You can check it out

Comment: Changing the cast condition to include the Time.time check in the if statement does resolve the issue, but I need to figure out why my current implementation isn't working since the CooldownManager function will be handling multiple spell cooldowns of varying length. I'd rather not have all the checks be within the if statements of the Cast function.

Comment: Can you try to change the calling order inside the if block. i.e set `aUsable = false;`  then call `spell.SetTrigger("explosionA");`